# WTF Forms (Flask)- FormField - FieldList, Validation don't work

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

Iam trying to create a ListItem Form using WTF Fields, FormField, FieldList:

**forms.py**

```
class WarehouseTicketItemForm(Form):
      description = StringField(u'Description', validators=[Required()])
      quantity = IntegerField(u'Quantity', validators=[Required()])

class WarehouseTicketForm(Form):
      spot_id = SelectField(u'Spot', coerce=int)
      items = FieldList(FormField(WarehouseTicketItemForm), min_entries = 3)
```

**warehouse_ticket_form.html**

```
<form action="" method='POST'>
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  {{ form.spot_id }} <br>
  {% for item in form.items %}
    {{ item }}
  {% endfor %}
 <button type="submit" name="button">Save it</button>
```

**warehouse_tickets.py**

```
@coordinator.route('/warehouses/tickets/update', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update_warehouses_tickets():
   page = dict(title="Warehouse Ticket")
   form = WarehouseTicketForm()
   form.spot_id.choices = [(s.id, s.name)
                           for s in Spot.query.filter_by(status=True)]
   if form.validate_on_submit():
       print form.data
   return render_template('coordinators/warehouses/warehouse_ticket_form.html',
                        page=page, form=form)
```

Submitting the form  "print form.data" doesn't return anything ...

I can't figure out that I am missing

Comment: Is your `<form>` tag properly closed?

Comment: It's also possible that the `action` attribute needs to specify the actual page.  Since it seems that it's being redirected to the current page, `action='/'` or `action='.'` should suffice. Any reason you're not using quickforms?

Comment: Ty both for the suggestions. I finally figure out that for each new 'item' form a crsf token is needed. For that I had to override WarehouseTicketItemForm init function by setting crsf token to False.

Comment: I had first thought it was a csrf token problem. But because you were using `hidden_tag()` I had assumed csrf tokens were automatically generated?

Answer (score 1):

I would put the validation as a parameter for the items field.

```
class WarehouseTicketForm(Form):
    spot_id = SelectField(u'Spot', coerce=int)
    items = FieldList(FormField(WarehouseTicketItemForm), min_entries = 3, validators=[Required()])
```

Comment: When you do this, it attempts to run that validation on the FieldList data, not individually for each field. This happens to work for `Required()` / `DataRequired()` if the use case is that there is at least one field of data, but that field could have two empty fields and this would incorrectly pass validation.